# Python module with methods imported from a sub-module into root namespace

Tags: python, module

I want to create a Python module that works like NumPy. The methods are not only sub-modules in the leaves of the tree from the module source. There is a root module containing many methods that I can call directly, and there are also sub-modules. The problem is the root methods must be defined somewhere. I was thinking to have a directory structure:

```
module/
  __init__.py
  core.py
  stuff1.py
  submodule/
    __init__.py
    stuff2.py
    stuff3.py
```

Now that I want is for everything inside "core" to be imported into the "module" namespace, as if it were a module.py file, and the contents of core.py were inside this module.py. The problem is that module is a directory instead of a file, so how do I define these methods that should sit in the root of the module?

I tried putting "from core import *" inside **init**.py, but that didn't work. (EDIT: Actually it does.)

Should I have the core methods inside a "module.py" file, and also a module directory? I don't know if that works, but it looks pretty awkward.

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried putting "from core import *" inside init.py, but that didn't work."? What exactly did you try, and what went wrong? You ought to be able to put something like   `from module.core import Clazz  print Clazz()` into `module/__init__.py` and see the output (something like `<module.core.Clazz object at 0x00BBAA90>`) when you import the module. Also remember that `from module import *` does not import any names that start with an underscore.

Comment: Henry, that works, but after the import you will get "NameError: name 'Clazz' is not defined". I want the contents of core.py to be loaded inside "module" after I do "import module". Importing core inside __init__ (e.g. import module.core as module) appears to work for whatever else is inside the init script, but not in the shell where I imported "module".

Comment: I added an answer to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out information about the [`__all__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44834/90322) list. It allows you to define what names are exported.

Tag it as such and you can setup a function to determine what to pull in from your submodules:

```
@property
all(self):
    #Whatever introspective code you may want for your modules
    __all__ += submodule.__all__
```

If you just want the whole damn shabang in module space, here's a way:

```
$ ipython
In [1]: from foomod import *

In [2]: printbar()
Out[2]: 'Imported from a foreign land'

In [3]: ^D
Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)?
$ ls foomod/
__init__.py __init__.pyc    core.py         core.pyc        submodule
$ grep . foomod/*.py 
foomod/__init__.py:from foomod.core import *
foomod/core.py:def printbar():
foomod/core.py:     return "Imported from a foreign land"
```

... and if we make `__init__.py` empty:

```
$ echo > foomod/__init__.py
$ ipython

In [1]: from foomod import *

In [2]: printbar()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-ba5b6693441e> in <module>()
----> 1 printbar()

NameError: name 'printbar' is not defined
```

Comment: Hi, Jeff. I'm not sure what you mean, what else do I have to do for that code to work? Is this all that is supposed to go inside module/__init__.py?

The documentation says specifically that __all__ relates to "from module import *"... It actually lists all that should be automatically imported, then? It's not just when you use "from xxx *"? That is a pretty bad way of explaining things in the documentation then.

Anyway, I want the contents of core to be part or the module namespace, not just import module.core automatically when module is imported.

Answer (score 5):

What I think you want is to be able to do this:

```
# some_other_script.py

import module
# Do things using routines defined in module.core
```

What happens when you ask Python to `import module` is (in a *very* basic sense), `module/__init__.py` is run, and a `module` object is created and imported into your namespace. This object (again, very basically) encompasses the things that happened when `__init__.py` was run: name definitions and so on. These can be accessed through `module.something`.

Now, if your setup looks like this:

```
# module/__init__.py

from module.core import Clazz
c = Clazz()
print c # Note: demo only! Module-level side-effects are usually a bad idea!
```

When you import `module`, you'll see a print statement like this:

```
<module.core.Clazz object at 0x00BBAA90>
```

Great. But if you then try to access `c`, you'll get a `NameError`:

```
# some_other_script.py
import module # prints "<module.core.Clazz object at 0x00BBAA90>"
print c # NameError (c is not defined)
```

This is because you haven't imported `c`; you've imported `module`. If instead your entry-point script looks like this:

```
# some_other_script.py
import module # prints "<module.core.Clazz object at 0x00BBAA90>"
print module.c  # Access c *within module*
```

Everything will run fine. This will **also** work fine with `from core import *` and/or `from module import *`, but I (and PEP8) advise against that just because it's not very clear what's going on in the script when you start mucking around with wild imports. For clarity:

```
# module/core.py

def core_func():
    return 1
```

```
# module/__init__.py

from core import *
def mod_func():
    return 2
```

The above is really pretty much fine, although you might as well make `core` "private" (rename to `_core`) to indicate that there's no reason to touch it from outside the package anymore.

```
# some_other_script.py

from module import *

print core_func() # Prints 1
print mod_func() # Prints 2
```

Comment: Well, it worked, thanks! I messed something up the first time I tried it. :/